# Sending HTML email to multiple recipients using Google Sheet and AppScript

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script that helps me send bulk HTML emails to multiple recipients.
In my Google Sheet file Col 1 contains the email address and Col 2 has the Name of the recipient. 
The one more thing i am trying to achieve and got stuck at is that i want to populate each email with the name of the recipient. For example , i am sending email to xxx@domain.com , i would like the email to start with "Dear xxx" and so on for all recipients.

How can this be done?

My code is as follows:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lr = ss.getLastRow(); 
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var subjectLine = "Test";
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('email'); 
      var email = htmlOutput.getContent();


      MailApp.sendEmail( currentEmail, "test", email, { htmlBody: email } ) 


    }      
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to find the `@` character and split the array into a substring to only get the characters positioned before @. Then, you can just add it to your `htmlBody` parameter. For example:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lr = ss.getLastRow(); 
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var subjectLine = "Test";
      var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('email'); 
      var email = htmlOutput.getContent();

      //My changes start here
      var index = currentEmail.indexOf('@');
      var name = currentEmail.substr(0, index); //chars from position 0 to index

      var head = '<html><body>Dear ' + name + ': <br />';

      MailApp.sendEmail( currentEmail, "test", email, { htmlBody: head + email } ) //You can add + '</body></html>' at the end if it's necessary.


    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a placeholder in the email body and replacing it with the name you want to use?

For example, the HTML email body template could be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
 </head>
 <body>
       <h1>Dear {0},</h1>
       <p>Let's try Apps Script!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then changing your original script a bit:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var lr = ss.getLastRow(); 

  for (var i=2; i<=lr; i++){

    var userEmail = ss.getRange('A'+i).getValue();
    var userName = ss.getRange('B'+i).getValue();
    var subject = 'Test Personalized Mass Email';
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SampleEmail'); 
    var email = htmlOutput.getContent();
    email = email.replace('{0}', userName);

    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, email, { htmlBody: email });

    }  
}
```